# malloc и realloc

Tags: c, указатели, память

Есть функции в Си для выделения памяти `malloc` и `realloc`. Вот я на скорую руку набросал код:

```
char *test;
test = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2); // По идеи я выделил место под 2 символов char
strcpy(test, "Hello world"); // Тут я записал Hello world хотя я выделил место всего под 2 символа
printf("%d", sizeof(test)); // Тут мне показывает 8, что это за 8, откуда оно взялось ?
test = (char *)realloc(test, sizeof(char) *4); // Добавляем еще место под 4 символа ( непонятно зачем правда, потому что Hello World как-то записалось хотя я выделил всего место под 2 символа
printf("%d", sizeof(test)); // Выводится 8, опять 8..откуда?
free(test);
```

Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить как это вообще работает? Может я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Для справки: `sizeof(char)` по определению равен 1

Comment: ну это я вкурсе

Comment: по коду не скажешь :)

Comment: Специально так делаю, что бы вошло в привычку писать так, ибо у разных типов разная величина

Comment: в таком случае, имеет смысл, да.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *test;
```

Объявили указатель

```
test = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2); // По идеи я выделил место под 2 символов char
```

Именно

```
strcpy(test, "Hello world"); // Тут я записал Hello world 
                             // хотя я выделил место всего под 2 символа
```

Записали в память, в которую писать нельзя. Undefined behaviour включает и такое поведение, когда запись выполняется за разрешенные пределы молча :)

```
printf("%d", sizeof(test)); // Тут мне показывает 8, что это за 8, откуда оно взялось ?
```

Размер указателя (каковым является ваша переменная `test`) в вашей системе - 64-разрядной

```
test = (char *)realloc(test, sizeof(char) *4); // Добавляем еще место 
      // под 4 символа ( непонятно зачем правда, потому что
      // Hello World как-то записалось хотя я выделил всего место под 2 символа
```

Не еще, а просто для 4 символов.

```
printf("%d", sizeof(test)); // Выводится 8, опять 8..откуда?
```

Именно столько места в памяти занимает переменная `test`. А не то, на что она указывает.

```
free(test);
```

Освобождение выделенной памяти.

Comment: Можете тогда привести пример правильного кода? А то я что-то не понимаю))

Comment: Просто выделяйте достаточное количество памяти, и все. И - если это вас утешит - то этот код, скомпилированный VC++, приводит к аварийному завершению. Узнать по указателю, сколько памяти выделено, в C/C++ нельзя - так что вы должны помнить эту величину сами.

Comment: Узнать-то на самом деле можно, но такая операция уже сама со себе UB. http://www.cyberforum.ru/post4956590.html

Comment: Указатель `определили`, а не только `объявили`.

Comment: @alexolut У меня *подписи* к строкам, а не *надписи*. `char*text` - именно объявили.

Comment: @kff Это уже не С/С++. И даже если вы знаете структуру менеджера - то указатель, который вы где-то получаете, может быть не на начало...

Comment: @Harry это определение (выделение памяти на стеке) переменной указателя. Если добавить extern - было бы исключительно объявление.